# Take input form keyboard and see if it matches format

Tags: java, regex, string, if-statement

I am trying to write a program that take user input from the keyboard and is called year. If the input equals a 4 digit year, output the year. If the input equals 2 digits add it to 2000 and output that. I wanted to use a switch statement but still confused on how to format it correctly. I decided to go with a If/else statement for my own sake. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String FULL_YEAR = "[0-9]{4}";
    final String TWO_YEAR ="[0-9]{2}";
    System.out.println("Please enter a year");
    String Year = scan.next();

    if (Year.matches(FULL_YEAR)) {
        System.out.println("The year is " + Year);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Year");
    } if (Year.matches(TWO_YEAR)) {
        System.out.println("The year is " + 2000+Year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an else if. Looks like you're almost there. Change it to:

```
    if (Year.matches(FULL_YEAR))
    {
        System.out.println("The year is " + Year);
    }
    else if (Year.matches(TWO_YEAR))
    {
        System.out.println("The year is " + 2000 + Year);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Year");
    }
```

As an aside, your code will be easier to read if you use java naming conventions. In particular, variables should not start with upper case letters (i.e. `Year` should be `year`). You should also close the scanner when you are done with it (`scan.close()`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but why would you use (scan.close())

Comment: @EthanCollins If you don't close your resources it can cause a memory leak, which basically means you have a pointer hanging around that the garbage collector can never clean up but which you are not going to use. You can search for memory leaks if you want more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

Read your code. If the first condition matches the `YY` format, it prints out the `Invalid year` no matters it's valid.

Use the `if-else` statement like here:

```
if (Year.matches(FULL_YEAR)) {
    System.out.println("The year is " + Year);
} else if (Year.matches(TWO_YEAR)) {
    System.out.println("The year is " + 20 + Year);
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Year");
}
```

---

By the way, you'd to print out for example the year `2016` `(20 + Year)` instead of `200016` `(2000 + Year)` since both are represented as Strings in the `println()` method. The operator `+` in that concatenates Strings instead of adding numbers. Both `2000` and `Year` are different data types.

To add a String and an Integer use any of:

```
System.out.println("The year is " + (2000 + Integer.parseInt(Year)));
System.out.println("The year is " + 20 + Year);
```

---

One more thing: Don't forget to close the resources when you don't need them anymore with `scan.close();`

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement compares the `String` object in its expression with the expressions associated with each `case` label as if it were using the `String.equals` method; consequently, the comparison of `String` objects in `switch` statements is case sensitive. The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from `switch` statements that use `String` objects than from chained `if-then-else` statements.
 [Reference URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)